# How to find the client's application port during communication

Tags: tcp, network, firewall, security

After reading firewall rules about inbound and outbount I have some questions and the most sources focus on the server's ports.

What happens to the client side when is trying to make a connection to port 25 (SMTP) from what port is the connection going, same 25 or a random one, is there any security issue with the client on his open port, can other people make requests there? How to see the port of the client when running lets say `telnet hostname target_port`. Is client a right terminology because I understand that there are biderectional connections. Why client's firewall accept the response from the server?

Comment: See [Ephemeral Ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port)

Comment: Looks like ephemeral port was the key for searching!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What happens to the client side when is trying to make a connection to port 25 (SMTP) from what port is the connection going, same 25 or a random one, is there any security issue with the client on his open port,

No. The port is not "open" (ie. listening = accepting connection attempts from elsewhere). It's only used for the current socket connection.

> can other people make requests there?

No.

> How to see the port of the client when running lets say `telnet hostname target_port`.

Telnet is a terminal client. You can't use it to examine any running connection. Each OS has various utilities like Windows's `netstat` that show you the various open or listening ports.

> Is client a right terminology because I understand that there are biderectional connections.

"Client" is a term used on the application layer (which is off-topic here). If you look at a TCP socket you've got a "listener" (usually the server) and the "initiator" (usually the client).

> Why client's firewall accept the response from the server?

Because a firewall is usually stateful: it remembers that the client has initiated a connection elsewhere and permits the reverse traffic as well.

Comment: Can you describe the "No."

Comment: The second "No"? It's the same answer as above.

Answer (score 0):

> same 25 or a random one

Random, see [Ephemeral port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port).

> is there any security issue with the client on his open port, can other people make requests there?

No, it is only as the source of a specific connection and is not accepting new connections on this port.

> How to see the port of the client when running lets say telnet hostname target_port

You can see the port with a packet capture (Wireshark), netstat (syntax depends on the system) etc. You can get the port based on `getsockname` in your own application but you cannot see the port just from within telnet or other application - unless these specifically provide a way for this (usually not).

> Why client's firewall accept the response from the server?

Likely because this is a [stateful firewall](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/61071/if-youre-behind-a-firewall-and-all-the-ports-are-blocked-how-is-your-browser-a/61072#61072).